# Column merge and shift elements in a Dataframe row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
    0         1    2   3    4    5   6    7      8     9   10 11  12      13  14      15
0   0  19780116  930   1  A0X   62  63    5    6.0  63.0  80 -26   0  33CATA  11     NaN
1   1  19780116  930   3  C21   57  58  105  107.0  61.0  75  18   1  33CATA  11     NaN
2   2  19780116  930   4  B01  -17 -16   21   12.0  28.0   1 -28   0  33CATA  11     NaN
3   3  19780117  750   3  C21   67  69   95  137.0  70.0  72  18   1  44CATA  11     NaN
4   4  19780117  750   6  A01    -   4    -    2.0  53.0  28  23   1     -27   0  44CATA
```

In the last row (and several others in the full dataframe) the negative signs are misplaced.

My question is if a negative sign is there at `i-th` position then it should merge `i+1 th` element and shift all other row elements to the left such that it the final output should be

```
    0         1    2   3    4   5     6      7      8     9  10  11  12      13    14  15
0   0  19780116  930   1  A0X  62  63.0    5.0    6.0  63.0  80 -26   0  33CATA  11.0 NaN
1   1  19780116  930   3  C21  57  58.0  105.0  107.0  61.0  75  18   1  33CATA  11.0 NaN
2   2  19780116  930   4  B01 -17 -16.0   21.0   12.0  28.0   1 -28   0  33CATA  11.0 NaN
3   3  19780117  750   3  C21  67  69.0   95.0  137.0  70.0  72  18   1  44CATA  11.0 NaN
4   4  19780117  750   6  A01  -4  -2.0   53.0   28.0  23.0   1 -27   0  44CATA   NaN NaN
```

Comment: how to you load the data in a dataframe? from read_csv? from a url?... it is possible that you can avoid it when loading the dataframe

Comment: @Ben.T From an url. I do not think it is possible to avoid because the delimiter is \s and there is a space between "-" and the number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Setup

```
>>> df

    0         1    2   3    4    5   6    7      8     9  10  11  12      13  14      15
0   0  19780116  930   1  A0X   62  63    5    6.0  63.0  80 -26   0  33CATA  11     NaN
1   1  19780116  930   3  C21   57  58  105  107.0  61.0  75  18   1  33CATA  11     NaN
2   2  19780116  930   4  B01  -17 -16   21   12.0  28.0   1 -28   0  33CATA  11     NaN
3   3  19780117  750   3  C21   67  69   95  137.0  70.0  72  18   1  44CATA  11     NaN
4   4  19780117  750   6  A01    -   4    -    2.0  53.0  28  23   1     -27   0  44CATA
```

#### Solution

```
c = df.copy()
m1 = c.eq('-')
m2 = m1.shift(axis=1, fill_value=False)

c.update(c.astype(str)[m2].radd('-').astype(float))
c = c.mask(m1)

i = np.argsort(c.isna(), axis=1)
c[:] = c.values[np.arange(len(c))[:, None], i]
```

#### Explanations

Create a copy of the dataframe named as `c` and compare with the character `-` to create a boolean mask `m1`

```
>>> m1 = c.eq('-')
>>> m1

      0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      10     11     12     13     14     15
0  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
1  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
2  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
4  False  False  False  False  False   True  False   True  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
```

Shift the boolean mask `m1` along `axis=1` to create a boolean mask `m2`

```
>>> m2 = m1.shift(axis=1, fill_value=False)
>>> m2

      0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      10     11     12     13     14     15
0  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
1  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
2  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
3  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
4  False  False  False  False  False  False   True  False   True  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
```

Update the values in the dataframe `c` by adding the character `-` to values indexed by boolean mask `m2`

```
>>> c.update(c.astype(str)[m2].radd('-').astype(float))
>>> c

    0         1    2   3    4    5     6    7      8     9  10  11  12      13  14      15
0   0  19780116  930   1  A0X   62  63.0    5    6.0  63.0  80 -26   0  33CATA  11     NaN
1   1  19780116  930   3  C21   57  58.0  105  107.0  61.0  75  18   1  33CATA  11     NaN
2   2  19780116  930   4  B01  -17 -16.0   21   12.0  28.0   1 -28   0  33CATA  11     NaN
3   3  19780117  750   3  C21   67  69.0   95  137.0  70.0  72  18   1  44CATA  11     NaN
4   4  19780117  750   6  A01    -  -4.0    -   -2.0  53.0  28  23   1     -27   0  44CATA
```

Mask the values in dataframe `c` corresponding to mask `m1`

```
>>> c = c.mask(m1)
>>> c

    0         1    2   3    4    5     6    7      8     9  10  11  12      13  14      15
0   0  19780116  930   1  A0X   62  63.0    5    6.0  63.0  80 -26   0  33CATA  11     NaN
1   1  19780116  930   3  C21   57  58.0  105  107.0  61.0  75  18   1  33CATA  11     NaN
2   2  19780116  930   4  B01  -17 -16.0   21   12.0  28.0   1 -28   0  33CATA  11     NaN
3   3  19780117  750   3  C21   67  69.0   95  137.0  70.0  72  18   1  44CATA  11     NaN
4   4  19780117  750   6  A01  NaN  -4.0  NaN   -2.0  53.0  28  23   1     -27   0  44CATA
```

Create a boolean mask with `isna` and apply `argsort` along `axis=1` to get the indices that would sort the dataframe `c` while also maintaining the relative order

```
>>> i = np.argsort(c.isna(), axis=1)
>>> i

    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
0   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
1   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
2   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
3   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
4   0   1   2   3   4   6   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15   5   7
```

`Sort` the values in the dataframe `c` along `axis=1` using the above indices obtained using `argsort` and assign the sorted values back to the dataframe `c`

```
>>> c[:] = c.values[np.arange(len(c))[:, None], i]
>>> c

    0         1    2   3    4    5     6     7      8     9  10   11  12      13    14  15
0   0  19780116  930   1  A0X   62  63.0     5    6.0  63.0  80  -26   0  33CATA  11.0 NaN
1   1  19780116  930   3  C21   57  58.0   105  107.0  61.0  75   18   1  33CATA  11.0 NaN
2   2  19780116  930   4  B01  -17 -16.0    21   12.0  28.0   1  -28   0  33CATA  11.0 NaN
3   3  19780117  750   3  C21   67  69.0    95  137.0  70.0  72   18   1  44CATA  11.0 NaN
4   4  19780117  750   6  A01 -4.0  -2.0  53.0   28.0  23.0   1  -27   0  44CATA   NaN NaN
```